# how to setup button to get file input back to being blank

Tags: jquery

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
 var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>");


 $weight.append($weightText);

        });

                var $imagefile = $('<input />')
            .attr({
                type: 'file',
                name: 'imageFile',
                class: 'imageFile'
            });

            $image.append($imagefile);

                var $imageclear = $('<input />')
            .attr({
                type: 'button',
                name: 'imageClear',
                class: 'imageClear',
                value: 'Clear File'
            });

$tr.append($image);
$tbody.append($tr); 

}
```

In the code above I have a file input and a button. What my question is, is that I want the button to be set up so that when the user clicks on the button, it removes the file url already selected by the user from the file input so that the file input could go back to being blank, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Bind a `click` `event` to the `button`, that actually replaces the file input element with a new one.

```
 $('<input />')
  .attr({
      type: 'button',
      name: 'imageClear',
      class: 'imageClear',
      value: 'Clear File'
  }).click(function(){
      $('#fileInputId').replaceWith('<input type="file" id="fileInputId" class="imageFile" name="imageFile" />');
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Sorry, I hit submit too early.

Wrap the file input in a div or span, and reset the HTML of that container with the container's HTML. I prefer this method because it is more general (could be placed in a plugin), and doesn't require me to respecify the input HTML in JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/nm4rV/

```
<span class="inputFile-wrap"><input type="file" class="inputFile" /></span>

<button type="button">Reset</button>

$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('.inputFile-wrap').html($('.inputFile-wrap').html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to replace the content of a file element with the content of the same file element? This will not reset the value of file element, you must replace it.

Comment: i hadn't finished yet; submitted answer too early.

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you want:

```
$('.imageClear').click(function() {
   $('.imageFile').val('');
});
```